Is it mandatory to give salaam to somone who is a bad person?
My eldest aunt's husband is not a good human being, although he is a Muslim. Is it mandatory for me to give him salam whenever I meet him in social gatherings? I stopped, but my mom scolds me.

According to most scholars: If someone is a Muslim but a Fasiq who commits major sins and has not repented - then it is acceptable to not initiate greeting to him, and to refrain from replying to his greeting.
Among the evidence for this, Bukhari has established a chapter in his Saheeh titled:

باب من لم يسلم على من اقترف ذنبا ولم يرد سلامه حتى تتبين توبته
Chapter: He who does not greet a person who has committed a sin and does not reply to his greeting until he has repented
— Bukhari

In which he has noted that Abdullah ibn Amr did not greet one who drank wine, and the incident of the verbal shunning of those who did not participate in Tabuk expedition without an excuse, where the Prophet ﵌ would not reply to their greeting.
There are also other reports where the sahaba refrained from talking with those who had committed a sin, such as Abdullah b. Mughaffal who said he would never talk to a person who committed a sin even after hearing a hadith prohibiting it. When he would not talk that also means that he would not greet.
Other than this, greeting is a form of showing affection and giving respect, and it wrong to display that towards one who disobeys Allah.
Ref:

وقد ذهب الجمهور إلى أنه لا يسلم على الفاسق
The view of the majority of the scholars is that a Fasiq is not to be greeted with salam
— Fath al-Bari

